# How to invoke the service built by Service Builder from portlet

Tags: liferay

The problem is that I created a Liferay portlet to invoke one

service(name is LocaleContentLocalServiceUtil) created by Liferay Service Builder before,

the service works in Liferay, but when I invoke the service

from portlet, I got NullerpointerException.

And I actived debug mode and found the return value of `PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate(LocaleContentLocalService.class.getName())` in LocaleContentLocalServiceUtil is null.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem, or can give me some directions, pls help me.

Comment: which liferay version?

Comment: What do you mean by service works in Liferay?

Comment: @Rajesh my liferay version is 6.1.0 CE

Comment: @MiroslavLigas I put the classes(persistence, service, util...) created by Service Builder to my liferay, and invoke the service (LocaleContentLocalServiceUtil) in the class DLFolderWrapper, then I tested it, the new functionality what I want does work. But I invoke the service(LocaleCOntentLocalServiceUtil) in my created portlet, the exception is thrown out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add following property in liferay-plugin-package.properties of your portlet. Make sure service jar is your classpath of deployed portlet webapps.

```
required-deployment-contexts=your-service-portlet
```

if this property is not there, try to copy your service-api.jar into tomcat/lib/ext and delete from service and all other portlet.

Comment: I tried set the property, now I get this error msg
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy339 cannot be cast to com.liferay.eip.portal.service.LocaleContentLocalService`

Comment: and I add these code to check the value of the return value from PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate
`Object klassObj = PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate(LocaleContentLocalService.class.getName());
System.out.println(klassObj.getClass().getName());`

I got com.sun.proxy.$Proxy339 when the LocaleContentLocalService class invoked either from portal or my created portlet. I don't understand why invoked from portal can be casted sucessfully, but failed from the invoked by my created portlet ?

Comment: its because of your service api jar copied at multiple places. try to put service api jar in tomcat/lib/ext and delete from webinf/lib of your portlet and service portlet

Comment: Finally I solved the problem. As you said, the reason is I have my service api at multiple places. I delete all the service api but left the one in tomcat/lib/ext, and now it works fine both on portlet and portal side. Thank you a lot ^^